# Spring Security OAuth2 - Is it possible to using client form login instead of the authorization server's form login?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

Is it possible to have the client submit credentials instead of getting redirected to the login page for the auth server and submitting the credentials through the auth server's login page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything is possible, but since the main reason for OAuth2 to have the auth code flow is to avoid that scenario, it defeats the object somewhat. What do you need OAuth2 for (maybe you should just authenticate everything locally in your app)?

Comment: I'm just testing out angularJS and Spring Security OAuth and trying to see what's possible. I understand the point of having the login form point to the  auth server. However, I'm trying many different things to test user experience. If you use basic auth you get a basic auth dialog from the browser. Is there a way to intercept the response and customize it in angularJS? I'm learning angularJS for the first time while testing out Spring Security OAuth2. I'm curious to see if I can have a uniform way of managing auth through OAuth2 while being flexible with the UI experience.

Comment: Did you see this blog series: https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v. That one is about oauth and there is an earlier one about basic vs having a login UI.

Comment: I followed that blog and the browser pops up a basic auth dialog which is nice, but I want to be able to customize that. I also followed the blog to test out the form login, but the login form exists on the auth server. I want to try and make a modal or a view that pops up and the user enters in the credentials which are then send back to the auth server (all in the OAuth2 flow).

Comment: I don't get it. If you use OAuth then by definition you want the auth server to do the authentication. Anyway, look at part II of the blog (or part V in the appendix) to see a login form.

Comment: I was just thinking about the case where you have a first party client and a 3rd party client. In a first party client redirecting to the auth server wouldn't make sense. In that case, would you say that OAuth does not make sense because it is your client, but for a 3rd party client it does make sense? Can you support both schemes on one auth server?

Comment: I wouldn't say that, no. Once you have externalized the authentication you can benefit from keeping all that in the same place. What happens when you have 2 "first party" apps, or 20, do you want to maintain all their authentication processes and UI assets at the same time?

Comment: How would you suppose Twitter and Facebook handle their log in though? It makes sense if you have a lot if internal first party apps or try to manage 3rd party apps accessing, but what if your 1st party client is a public facing website. You lose the ability to submit the credentials from the public site because you have to redirect to the auth server's login page (unless I'm not understanding something). What I'm trying to figure out is how to solve the UX/PM saying "Oh why is there a redirect that looks bad. I shouldn't leave the main site".

Comment: As far as the user is concerned he never feels he "left the main site" if all apps are branded the same. That's the way we do it on cloud foundry anyway, so I inagine Google, facebook et al. do it the same or similar.